# tosca test automation tool: how to change the node path for multiple objects

Tags: automation, tosca

we have a situation where the UI for the functionality introduced additional iframe. now when tried to execute, it failed. is there way we can bulk update object's path ? or manually change the node path to have this intermediate iframe node for all objects.  we are trying to avoid going to each object level change to save effort and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Tosca's nodepath is a path to a resource. As such, you can't edit it directly. It changes when you move an object from one folder to another. In TestCases, the structure of the XModule from which an XTestStep is modeled also affects its nodepath. That means trying to change the nodepath of XTestSteps means updating the XModules from which they're modeled, first.  Unfortunately, that does break any test steps modeled on the module in question.

As far as performing a bulk edit operation, editable properties can be bulk modified by leveraging the 'Search from' dialog to find the objects that need to be modified.  From the search results, bulk update operations can be performed.

Assuming you only need to modify properties of those existing objects, multiple-select them from the search results and bulk update them by right clicking and selecting 'Modify' and then the appropriate property from the context menu.  This brings up a 'Modify attribute' dialog for you to enter the new value.  The dialog allows for either replacing the existing values entirely, or for partially updating them using Regex by checking the checkbox.  If the "object's path" you are referring to is an XPath property on a module attribute, this is the way to go.

In some cases, particularly with XTestSteps, especially after changing the structure of the XModule from which they are modeled, altering a property of the existing objects won't work.  In these cases, the 'Modify' section of the search dialog allows for inserting a new object.  To do this, with the 'Modify' section is expanded, drag your replacement object onto the 'Drop element here to insert' button and 'Modify All'.  Then, you can go back and delete the outdated version.  The first screenshot in the 'TQL - Step by step' documentation linked below shows this dialog with the expanded 'Modify' section.

TQL - Step by step:
https://documentation.tricentis.com/tosca/1400/en/content/articles/tql_step_by_step.htm

Modify objects via the context menu:
https://documentation.tricentis.com/tosca/1400/en/content/tosca_commander/modifying_context_menu.htm

Comment: thanks Alex. As per the suggestion, we tried using search  -TBOX. basically, we tried 2 options a. searched for all objects  and then tried to modify nodepath value b.  searched for all webelement  and add / introduce new iframe. However, a. nodepath property not in the modifiable attribute.  b. in this case, we are not able to add iframe element. we tried with insertafter. Field where we can drag new iframe is disabled.

Comment: Hello Jeff.  Tosca's nodepath is a path to a resource.   As such, you can't edit it directly.  It changes when you move an object from one folder to another.  In TestCases, the structure of the XModule from which an XTestStep is modeled also affects its nodepath.  That means trying to change the nodepath of XTestSteps means updating the XModules from which they're modeled, first.  Unfortunately, altering a module's structure does mess up any teststeps using those modules.  That's where the second process I outlined earlier comes in.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Commander https://support-hub.tricentis.com/open?id=show_search_result&product=tosca&type=product_manual&path=%2Ftosca%2F1500%2Fen%2Fcontent%2Ftosca_commander%2Fworkspaces_objects.htm

as per the link, it says you can rearrange objects from the nav tree

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks Andy for taking looking into this.